# VPN on specific websites only

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, router, openvpn

An openVPN connection in my Ubuntu 14.04. I would like to use that VPN when I access to some specific websites only.

For example, 
go to google.com through VPN,
but access stackoverflow.com without VPN.

I don't want to switch the VPN connection on and off, how could it possible? Have no idea how to do, router tables? or some other configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by appending

```
route 123.123.0.0 255.255.0.0 net_gateway 5
```

in .ovpn file, then launch the VPN by

```
openvpn --config this-file.ovpn
```